# How to add two time outputs in bash

Tags: bash, date, time

I want to calculate in bash the average time spent by several commands. The output of time command is min:sec.milisec.

I don't know how to add two outputs of this kind in bash and in final to calculate the average.

I tried to convert the output with date but the output is "date: invalid date `0:01.00'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a three part answer

### Part one

First, use the `TIMEFORMAT` variable to output only seconds elapsed. Then you can add this directly

From `man bash`

> **TIMEFORMAT**
>                 The value of this parameter is used as a format string specifying how the timing  information
>                 for  pipelines  prefixed  with  the  time reserved word should be displayed.  The % character
>                 introduces an escape sequence that is expanded to a time value  or  other  information.   The
>                 escape sequences and their meanings are as follows; the braces denote optional portions.

Here is an example which outputs only seconds with a precision of 0, i.e. no decimal point. Read part three why that's important.

```
TIMEFORMAT='%0R'; time sleep 1
1
```

### Part two

Second, how do we capture the output of `time`? It's actually a bit tricky, here's how you do capture the time from the command above

```
TIMEFORMAT='%0R'; time1=$( { time sleep 1; } 2>&1 )
```

### Part three

How do we add the times together and get the average?

In bash we use the `$(( ))` construct to do math. Note that `bash` does not natively support floating point so you will be doing integer division (hence the precision 0.)  Here is a script that will capture the `time` from two commands and output each of the individual times and their average

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEFORMAT='%0R'
time1=$( { time sleep 1; } 2>&1 )
time2=$( { time sleep 4; } 2>&1 )
ave=$(( (time1 + time2) / 2))

echo "time1 is $time1 | time2 is $time2 | average is $ave"
```

#### Output

```
time1 is 1 | time2 is 4 | average is 2
```

If integer division is a non-starter for you and you want precision, as long as you don't mind calling the external binary `bc`, you can do this quite easily.

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEFORMAT='%3R'
time1=$( { time sleep 1; } 2>&1 )
time2=$( { time sleep 4; } 2>&1 )
ave=$( bc <<<"scale=3; ($time1 + $time2)/2" )

echo "time1 is $time1 | time2 is $time2 | average is $ave"
```

#### Output

```
time1 is 1.003 | time2 is 4.003 | average is 2.503
```

Comment: Really nice explanation. I wanted to the answer for this question too. +1 :)

Comment: @OctavianRinciog I'm glad this is what you wanted. If this answer is sufficient for you, please click on the checkmark to the left of my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For the example i'll use a variable preinitialized:

```
time="54:32.96";

minutes=$(echo "$time" | cut -d":" -f1)
seconds=$(echo "$time" | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1)
millis=$(echo "$time" | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d"." -f2)

#Total time in millis
totalMillisOne=$(($millis+$seconds*1000+$minutes*60000))
```

You do this with every command and you save it in diferent vars, and then you do the average:

```
let avMillis=$totalMillisOne+$totalMillisTwo
let avMillis=$avMillis/2
```

And you output it in the same input format:

```
let avSeconds=$avMillis/1000
let avMillis=$avMillis-$avSeconds*1000;

let avMinutes=$avSeconds/60;
let avSeconds=$avSeconds-$avMinutes*60;

echo "${avMinutes}:${avSeconds}.${avMillis}"
```

Comment: In `bash`, you could streamline the `echo` parts with `cut -d: -f1 <<< $time`, for example.  You could also, I think, do the manipulation of the strings in pure Bash, avoiding invoking external commands.  I would probably do the whole operation in one Perl (Python, awk, ...) command, but that's in part because I've not internalized all the facilities available in `bash`.  Also note that the time value shown will be converted to 3272.096 instead of 3272.960.

Comment: Yeah, i know, i'm only into bash very lightly, learned while doing the degree. i wish i knew more. Also, you're right with the format output. I just do it supposing the specifications given. Thank you so much for your comment :)